# What is the maximum size of ATAG in linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, bootloader, atag

I would like to PASS a bulk data (around 4500 bytes) from bootloader to Linux kernel using custom ATAG. I am not able to find maximum size allocated for the ATAG parameters list which is passed to linux kernel. 
Can anybody help me find out this size?
Is it possible to change the maximum size of ATAG list?

Comment: How can anyone know whether it's possible to change some aspect of your bootloader without knowing _at the very least_ what bootloader it is?

Comment: I think that 4k is about standard, but I would suggest you pass the data another way.  Send a buffer/pointer value in the *atag* and then use the data.  You need to reserve the memory from Linux.  Then there is no issue and it should be device tree compatible.  You should also take a look at the firmware API; it sounds more like what you want?